# How do you stop executing after exiting first method

Tags: java, selenium

I have two methods one is dependent on another when it returns `true` I want to **stop the script**. I have to check `test1` first and then `test2`, I want to know how to stop running script if it returns `true` on `test1` when it clicks stop, so it would not run `test2`. What is the most efficient way to write it or should I use switch case?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   a.test1("stop");
   a.test2("slow");
}

public void test1(String check1) {
    if (check1.equalsIgnoreCase("Go")) {
        go.click();
    } else if (check1.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
        stop.click();
        return;
    } else if (check1.equalsIgnoreCase("slow")) {
        slow.click();
    } else if (check1.equalsIgnoreCase("walk")) {
        walk.click();
    }
}

public void test2(String check) {
    if (check.equalsIgnoreCase("go")){
        check.click()
    }
    else if (check.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {           
        stop.click();
        return;
    }
    else if (check.equalsIgnoreCase("slow")) {
        slow.click();
    } else if (check.equalsIgnoreCase("walk")) {
        walk.click();
    }
    fast.click();
    faster.click();
}
```

Comment: Your methods are `void` and `slow.lick();` is an amusing typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.exit(0);
```

fully **finishes the program**. If you want to know more about the `exit` method, I suggest reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit(int).

To `exit` if a specific condition is `true`, simply call

```
if(/*your condition*/)
{
  System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: ok Do you think boolean method will help or put test2 method inside of test1 method?

Comment: @johnnyhackenko a boolean method is fine